# count value with wildcard AND without double

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula which is working with excel 2016.
The task is a summary sheet with has a datafeed from a csv-dataset, it is updated all week. the sheet with the csv is called "data".
the other one is called "summary", so every cell-link starts with data!$... etc.
the data-sheet contains in column a three types of values:
beginning with nb, pc and vc. every values is looking like pc10000 and exist mostly 10-20 times. i need to count every values **once** without the doubles for the summary divided by the value-classes pc, nb and vc. so i think it needs to be done with a wildcard like pc*.
All ideas collected from google and youtube didn't worked out so far. maybe someone can help me out with a smart idea?
thx in advice,
chris

=sum / countif
array-formulas

Comment: Please, add example input and expected output. Remember you can use [Table to Markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

Answer (score 0):

So this may help if I followed what you tried to explain:

[image]

Unique gets a list avoiding duplicates which is then used to count.

Then how many times is "pc"  in that list is the second count.